# Why are malloc-allocated memory values assigned with i++ instead of i+4 (in the case of an int being 4 bytes large)?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-address

My mind is confused and blown right now and hopefully someone can help me deconfuse it /put me on the right path again.

Correct me if I'm wrong but in C, you use malloc to 'reserve' / get a **certain amount of space in memory in bytes**.

So `int* ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));` would **allocate 40 Bytes of memory** / assign a pointer to that region in memory to the variable/pointer ptr (suppose that on this machine an **int is 4 bytes large**).

---

What I don't understand is when you assign the array with values why i is i++ (1 increment) instead of i + 4 aka the size of an int. It would make sense since we have a 40 Bytes block of memory and we iterate 10 times à +4 Bytes => 40 Bytes.

Code Example:
*Suppose, for the sake of simplicity, a function random() returns a random integer.*

(The correct way -> 10 random ints):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    *(ptr + i) = random();
}
```

(My thought of i+4 Bytes, produces weird results, wrong way):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i+=4) {
    *(ptr + i) = random();
}
```

**My question is, why does ptr + i (i+1) select the correct address of each int when an int is 4 bytes large and we even reserve 40 Bytes of memory, not 10. aka why is ptr + i (i+4) wrong?**

(To my brain it makes sense to iterate i+4 instead of 1. start / ptr assigned through malloc => 0x400, an int is 4 bytes large so the next address / next int is at 0x404, 0x408 etc.... not 0x401, 0x402 ....)

Comment: That's just how C is specified.  For the same reasons that `array[i]` is equivalent to `*(array + i)`.

Comment: Offsetting a non-char pointer by anything other than a multiple of the sizeof() of the type is guaranteed to lead to an invalid location, so it makes sense to make that implicit. (and since char has sizeof()==1, then it doesn't need any special treatment)

Comment: Why are you assuming an `int` is 4 bytes?

Comment: @AndrewHenle as noted in the question, it's 4 Bytes large on *my machine* (irrelevant anyway since the main point of the question is the i++ part)

Comment: In C++, `ptr + i` is undefined behaviour. You can only do that **[only if](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4)** `ptr` points to an element of some array of `int`s. The pointer returned my `malloc` doesn't point to such an array.

Comment: @Evg as of C++20, it's fine as long as the type is trivially constructible due to IOC.

Comment: @Frank Does it (IOC) apply to arrays, too?

Comment: @Evg, AFAIK, IOC applies to any correctly-aligned memory location that doesn't hold an object yet. That includes arrays.

Comment: @Evg If that were the case, it would be impossible to use malloced memory for an array.

Comment: @dbush And which part of the C++17 standard makes this code well-formed? Malloced memory can be used for an array due to some additional support from compilers that add such a support because a lot of people rely on it. But it doesn't make pointer arithmetic on malloced memory a part of the standard. Likewise, a lot of people use unions for type punning. It works, and some compilers provide explicitly guarantees, but the standard says it's UB.

Comment: @Evg C++17 23.10.11p2: "*Effects:These functions have the semantics specified in the C standard library*"  C11 7.22.3: "*... The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated) ...*"

Comment: @Evg Also, the language surrounding adding/subtracting a pointer and an integer in both languages (C11 6.5.6p8 and C++17 8.7p4) while not identical basically say the same thing.

Comment: @dbush But there are neither objects of type `int` not an array of such objects at that location. The paper about IOC has `malloc` and `operator new` as primary motivating examples for changing the standard - *"When compiled with a C++ compiler, this code has undefined behavior, because `p->a` attempts to write to an `int` subobject of an `X` object, and this program never created either an `X` object nor an `int` subobject."* [P0593 Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](https://wg21.link/p0593)

Comment: @Evg Interesting that C++ never picked up the concept of an "effective type" which C had since C99.  Granted, object creation is more complex due to constructors, but still it's surprising that the C++ committee has only recently started to address this defect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic, and memory allocation, are two different things.

Pointer arithmetic is *always* done based on the type of the pointed-to object.  That is, pointer arithmetic always incorporates an automatic, implicit multiplication by that size.  So

```
int *p;
/* ... */
p++;
```

is always going to increment the address in `p` by `sizeof(int)` bytes.

It has to be this way because, among other things, pointer arithmetic simulates array access.  So it has to take the size of the pointed-to object into account in order for notations like

```
*(p + 1)
```

and

```
p[1]
```

to work properly.

The `malloc` function, on the other hand, always deals in bytes.  One reason -- perhaps *the* reason -- is precisely that `malloc` is a function.  When you say something like

```
malloc(10 * sizeof(int))
```

the number received by the `malloc` function on your machine is just 40.  `malloc` has no way of knowing whether that's 40 things of size 1, or 10 things of size 4, or one thing of size 40.  All it knows is it has to allocate 40 bytes.  (There are also requirements pertaining to alignment.)

If you wanted it to work differently -- if you wanted something like

```
int *ip = malloc(10);
```

to automatically scale by `sizeof(int)` -- it's hard to see how it could work in C.  (By contrast, in C++ there's `new[]`, which can and does take the size of the allocated object into account.)

Comment: The part where you explained that p++ increases it by type size made it click for me thank you so much! (And you gave me a new/right topic to research pointer arithmetic, thanks).

Answer (score 1):

If `p` is a pointer to an object of type `T`, then `p+1` yields the address of the next object of the pointed-to type; `p++` advances `p` to point to the next object.

Given

```
char  *cp = (char *)  0x1000;
short *sp = (short *) 0x1000; // assume 2-byte short
long  *lp = (long *)  0x1000; // assume 4-byte long
```

then the following are true:

```
       char            short           long
       +–––+           +–––+           +–––+
0x1000 |   | <––cp     |   | <––sp     |   | <-–lp
       +–––+           + - +           + - +
0x1001 |   | <-–cp+1   |   |           |   |
       +———+           +———+           + - +
0x1002 |   | <––cp+2   |   | <––sp+1   |   |
       +———+           + - +           + - +
0x1003 |   | <––cp+3   |   |           |   |
       +–––+           +–––+           +–––+
0x1004 |   | <––cp+4   |   | <––sp+2   |   | <––lp+1
       +———+           + - +           + - +
        ...             ...             ...
```